# Mathematics Meta chat room

Tags: discussion, chat, meta

I recently found that this site (meta) has a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2162/mathematics-meta) permanently attached to it:

> Welcome to chat for: Mathematics Meta
>   This is a general discussion room

Nobody posted there for **829 days**, but the room did not freeze for inactivity: apparently, <s>the "official" chat rooms never freeze</s> the system does not allow  *all* of site's rooms to be frozen.  This looks like a valuable feature of the room: in the specialized rooms attached to the main site we sometimes have to post filler just to prevent freezing.

[There are no room owners](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2162/mathematics-meta). So, my questions are:

1. Can this room be a useful addition to the main chat room? For example, to discuss the workings of the meta site itself?
2. And if so, who should the room owners be?

Comment: [The MO-room did freeze](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243?m=14413243#14413243). Perhaps it is the case that not *all* rooms of a site will freeze. There is not even really a notion of "official" chat room AFAIK.

Comment: Interesting. I though the official status is conferred by the fact that the room was not created by a regular user.

Comment: [This MSE feature-request for not freezing main](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100519/exclude-the-main-chat-room-from-automatic-freezing-deletion) is where I believe I saw the statement that there is no official room; the source is not official though.

Comment: As explained in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780/why-am-i-the-owner-of-the-chatroom/2781#2781), the room is assigned an owner if there is enough activity in the room. (Low activity room are viewed as not in a need of owner.)

Comment: The fact that the room is frozen seems strange to me. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226302/main-chatroom-for-a-se-site-and-chatroom-pruning) you can find some cases where even "main chatroom" was frozen. And [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17783789#17783789) is another example of a room which was kept unfrozen for a very long time. (See also [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13591/conversation/messages-from-feeds-and-freezing-rooms).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think the explanation that quid suggested (and you tested in chat before) is correct: the room does not freeze because it's the only room attached to the meta.math site.